# git-svn folder from existing custom SVN

Tags: git, git-svn, msysgit

I would like to use git-svn to work on an existing SVN repository having the following structure:

```
http://thesvn/project
  branch1
  branch2
  ...
```

I can't configure the svn remote to fetch the branches correctly. At the moment I have this config:

```
[svn-remote "svn"]
    url = http://thesvn/project
    branches = *:refs/remotes/branches/*
```

And when I try to `git svn fetch svn`, I get the following:

```
ref: 'refs/remotes/' ends with a trailing slash; this is not permitted by git or Subversion
```

Note that I'm working on Windows with msysgit. Any advice?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50404252/129550

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried init or clone of git-svn, e.g. `git svn clone -bproject http://thesvn/ project` ? You'd get something like this at your git config:

```
[svn-remote "svn"]
url = http://thesvn/
branches = project/*:refs/remotes/*
```

And that should work.

Comment: Hi Mykola, yes I tried but I'm only allowed to access `http://thesvn/project`, one level higher and I don't have permissions. I'm actually angry against such a repository structure but I'm struggling to find a way through all this anyhow. Nice suggestion anyway, thanks!

Comment: I would expect this scheme to also work if you don't have access to `http://thesvn`, although cannot guarantee without testing.

Comment: I tried again from the start with your configuration. Assume the project repository is at `http://thesvn/repos/project`. git-svn throws me the following error: `RA layer request failed: PROPFIND request failed on '/repos': PROPFIND of '/repos': 302 Found (http://thesvn) at /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/Git/SVN.pm line 148`. It really might be caused by my permissions here

Comment: Unable to connect to a repository at URL path not found

Comment: @fuzzyTew put a valid url accessible to you