# How do I migrate an SVN repository with custom structure to Git?

Tags: git-svn

I have a multi-module legacy project in SVN, where individual modules were released and tagged separately, resulting in the following structure:

```
trunk/
  project/
    moduleX/
    moduleY/
    moduleZ/
tags/
  moduleX-1.0/
  moduleX-1.1/
  moduleY-0.1/
  moduleZ-2.0/
```

Looks like the tags were created with `svn copy trunk/project/moduleX/ tags/moduleX-1.0/` etc, rather than `svn copy trunk/project/ tags/moduleX-1.0`

Is it possible to migrate such project to Git as a single repository, preserving history and creating appropriate tags?

Answer (score 0):

You need to manually configure git-svn.

1. Create empty repositories: `git init moduleX ; git init moduleY ; git init moduleZ`
2. Edit each gitconfig and add a git-svn section like:

moduleX/.git/config:

```ini
[svn-remote "svn"]
    url = svn://your-server/svn-repo
    fetch = trunk/project/moduleX:refs/remotes/svn/trunk
    tags = tags/moduleX-*:refs/remotes/svn/tags/*
```

moduleY/.git/config:

```ini
[svn-remote "svn"]
    url = svn://your-server/svn-repo
    fetch = trunk/project/moduleY:refs/remotes/svn/trunk
    tags = tags/moduleY-*:refs/remotes/svn/tags/*
```

moduleZ/.git/config:

```ini
[svn-remote "svn"]
    url = svn://your-server/svn-repo
    fetch = trunk/project/moduleZ:refs/remotes/svn/trunk
    tags = tags/moduleZ-*:refs/remotes/svn/tags/*
```

3. `git svn fetch` in each copy.

Comment: Ok, but won't this give me three independent repositories instead of single multi-module one? Or is there a way to combine them afterwards?

Comment: Oops, sorry! missed the `single repository` part. But, in that case, what would prevent you from plain `git svn clone -s`?

Comment: Because each tag contains only subdirectory related to specific module, rather than the whole structure (I updated the question).